# Select column values from DB for which the subsequent row does not have a specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table say MyTable has two columns `Id`, `Data` and has following records in it:

```
 Id Data
 ----------
 1. ABCDE00
 2. DEFGH11
 3. CCCCC21
 4. AAAAA00
 5. BBBBB10
 6. vvvvv00
 7. xxxxx88
```

Now what I want that all the records which have end with string `00` and does not have subsequent row having column ending with `11`.

So my output using this condition should be like this:

```
1. AAAAA00
2. vvvvv00
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the subsequent row? Tables inherently have no order, and the way you listed the sample data isn't sorted alphanumerically. So how do you sort?

Comment: subsequent row means the next row. Sorting doesn't matter actually and not required.

Comment: Yes it does, how else do we know what the next row is?

Comment: Is there any way to use PL SQL and use row_number()

Comment: You tagged your question `sql-server`, so no, you can't use PL-SQL. You can use `row_number()`, if you know the order by...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have made one extra column in table as ID and using that it worked. Initially I didn't have that.

Comment: ...if you didn't have the id column initially, how'd you assign it?  You'd essentially put the rows in random order.  Also, this question implies you have a multi-part key, which is bad (and other problematic things about your dataset anyways).

Comment: Actually I have created the table again having ID as Identity column. SO nothing serious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is not using sql server 2012,then they an try this

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1),col1 varchar(100))
insert into @t values
('ABCDE00')
,('DEFGH11')
,('CCCCC21')
,('AAAAA00')
,('BBBBB10')
,('vvvvv00')
,('xxxxx88')
;With CTE as
(
select *,case when CHARINDEX('00',reverse(col1))>0 then 1 end 
End00 from @t
)
,CTE1 as
(
select a.id,a.col1  from cte A
where exists
(select id from cte b where  a.id=b.id+1 and b.end00 is not null)
and CHARINDEX('11',reverse(a.col1))<=0

)

select a.id,a.col1  from cte A
where exists
(select id from cte1 b where  a.id=b.id-1 )
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer makes some assumptions:

- You have a column specifying the ordering.  Let me call it `id`.
- By "subsequent row" you mean the row with the next highest `id`.
- You are using SQL Server 2012+.

In that case, `lead()` does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(data order by id) as next_data
      from t
     ) t
where data like '%00' and (next_data not like '%11' or next_data is null);
```

Earlier versions of SQL Server have alternative methods for calculating `next_data`.